# Is it better to nest functions where possible in R?

Tags: r, function

It is common in R to write custom functions to do specialized work that is needed for a given dataset or analysis.  For example, these functions might lead to less repetitious code or could be vectorized to improve performance.  Moreover, functions can call other functions.

Imagine a situation in which one function, `bar()`, will only be called within another function, `foo()`.  In that case, is it better to create `bar()` *within* `foo()`, or *outside* of it?

Here is a simple example (which may not be elaborate enough to make the different strategies meaningfully distinct, but you can imagine—*or suggest ;-)*—complex functions that could be nested or not):

```
# within:
foo <- function(x){
  bar <- function(x){
    x <- x*2
    return(x)
  }

  x <- x+3
  x <- bar(x)
  return(x)
}

# outside:
bar <- function(x){
  x <- x*2
  return(x)
}
foo <- function(x){
  x <- x+3
  x <- bar(x)
  return(x)
}
```

I am wondering which would be preferable, and why?  (In case 'preferable' might seem vague to someone, here are specific criteria that might lead you to prefer one of the options.  I am also open to the idea that one is preferable by some criteria, while the other is preferable by other criteria.)

1. Would one way lead to cleaner, more readable code?  (This might apply when dealing with more, larger, and more complex functions than the examples, or be more important when code will be shared between colleagues.)
2. Are programmers less likely to make mistakes one way, or would one be easier to debug?
3. Is one faster, or easier to vectorize?  For example, does `bar()` get re-created every time `foo()` is run?
4. Is one more numerically stable, or less likely to crash?
5. (other reasons?)

Comment: My preference is to embed the function. A major reason for this is that the meaning of the function is clear to myself and other reviewing the code: the only purpose of the embedded function is to serve the outer function. I also have some vague feeling that garbage collection is cleaner, though have no evidence to support this.

Comment: If you're writing multiple variations of `foo` that all use the same `bar` function, then your best bet would be to create `foo` outside. Other than, you may be cluttering your global namespace/environment with multiple function definitions.

Comment: From a development sense and a testing sense, separate functions are easier to test and maintain. If you have an error, it is far clearer where and why. Operationally it makes little difference.

Comment: This [recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059004/binding-outside-variables-in-r) provides one use case for the need for inner functions.