# Binding outside variables in R

Tags: r, function, binding, environment

Suppose I have the following function:

```
g = function(x) x+h
```

Now, if I have in my environment an object named `h`, I would not have any problem:

```
h = 4
g(2)

## should be 6
```

Now, I have another function:

```
f = function() {
    h = 3
    g(2)
}
```

I would expect:

```
rm(h)
f()

## should be 5, isn't it?
```

Instead, I get an error

```
## Error in g(2) : object 'h' not found
```

I would expect `g` to be evaluated within the environment of `f`, so that the `h` in `f` will be bound to the h in g, as it was when I executed `g` within the `.GlobalEnv`. This does not happen (obviously). any explanation why? how to overcome this so that the function within the function(e.g. `g`) will be evaluated using the enclosing environment?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it seems as though R looks to the global scope for all variables not either defined in the function call or passed as parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a difference between the *enclosing environment* of a function, and its (parent) *evaluation frame*.

The enclosing environment is set when the function is defined. If you define your function `g` at the R prompt:

```
g = function(x) x+h
```

then the enclosing environment of `g` will be the global environment. Now if you call `g` from another function:

```
f = function() {
    h = 3
    g(2)
}
```

the parent evaluation frame is `f`'s environment. But this doesn't change `g`'s enclosing environment, which is a fixed attribute that doesn't depend on where it's evaluated. This is why it won't pick up the value of `h` that's defined within `f`.

If you want `g` to use the value of `h` defined within `f`, then you should also define `g` within `f`:

```
f = function() {
    h = 3
    g = function(x) x+h
    g(2)
}
```

Now `g`'s enclosing environment will be `f`'s environment (but be aware, this `g` is not the same as the `g` you created earlier at the R prompt).

Alternatively, you can modify the enclosing environment of `g` as follows:

```
f = function() {
    h = 3
    environment(g) <- environment()
    g(2)
}
```